# How to set the timezone in react admin v3?

Tags: javascript, timezone, utc, react-admin, date-fns

I am using react admin v3.

I have in postgresql a TimstampTz datatype.

Operators are located in Europe/Paris and Asia/Indochina.

I want to display the date for the local date time

And the corresponding value for a corresponding timezone.

Using format I am able to display a date parsed but I can't set any offset.

I am also able to modify the value, but I can not add the offset there because it will change the value.

How can I set timezone for displaying a date in react admin or how can i modify the display depending on a timezone without editing the value?